# Auto Update database column on a certain date

Tags: laravel

Im making a membership management system using laravel 5.8 for school project

I have a field on my database called "valid_until" which is an expiration date of the membership and "membership_status" which is the status of the membership.

What i want to happen is to update the field "membership_status" automatically when the date now is equal or > to the "valid_until" field.

Is there a way to do it on laravel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this with a cron job that will run every day or hour or whatever time frame you want. But you can't compare exact dates, you will probably have to check if `now` is greater than `valid_until` field.

Laravel has a nice library for making cron jobs. Check it out:
https://laravel.com/docs/scheduling

Comment: can i use cron job on windows ?

Comment: No, on windows you have task scheduler. But usually you use cron jobs on a server. And servers mostly run on linux. You rarely need a cron on your local machine. If you want to run a script that updates something in the database, you just do it manually. For example you can make a custom artisan command in laravel that does what you need it to do. And call it whenever you want like `php artisan your:command`. On a server you would make a cron/task that would run that command every x minutes/hours/days.